# Counting Button clicks with Javascript, passing the count to Wordpress loop, appending to isotope container

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to load post objects, and append them into an Isotope container.
I click a button (`#append`) and it grabs the `getItemElement`.

`getItemElement` is a wordpress loop.

I'm trying to pass the count to the wordpress loop so it can offset the loop and grab the next three posts, add three to the counter, and then grab the next three posts.

On first click it would add 3, bring the count to 8, then skip the first 8 posts, load the next 3, and stop. On second click it would add 3 to 8, skip the first 11 posts, and then load the next 3 and stop.

```
    var $appendcount = 5;
    $('#append').on( 'click', function() {
        $appendcount = $appendcount + 3;
        if($appendcount==23){$('#append').css('opacity','0.2');}
        // create new item elements
        var $elems = getItemElement().add();                    
        // append elements to container
        $container.append( $elems )
                  // add and lay out newly appended elements
                  .isotope( 'appended', $elems );
    });

    // Short Wordpress Loop />
    function getItemElement() {
      var $item = $('<?php $postcounter =' . $appendcount . '; $instaqueryappend = new WP_Query( array("offset"=>$postcounter, "cat"=>15, "posts_per_page"=>3) ); if ( $instaqueryappend->have_posts() ) : while ( $instaqueryappend->have_posts() ) : $instaqueryappend->the_post(); $postcounter++; $feat_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) ); ?><div class="element-item img append instagram img<?php echo $postcounter; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $feat_image; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $feat_image; ?>" alt=""></a></div><?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>');
      return $item;
    }
```

Comment: php and javascript run in different environments and at different times

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't possible directly, and may need AJAX to feed back to the PHP file the data. In essence, when the page is being loaded, the PHP command is implemented first, then HTML, and finally the JavaScript commands (assuming the JS content is in footer). If you want to pass values back to PHP, then you need to 'reload' the page with the correct data value. It's ideal and best to do everything in PHP.

Comment: Ah. Now that makes sense. So even though the php is triggered from a button press, it's actually pulled on the initial page load, and then displayed after the javascript fires?

Comment: no php runs before any html is created. All it does is output the values that exist at server stage (i.e. set by php). javascript works with its own variables, you can output php into javascript but, and for example, `$x=1;` will always be 1 in your js. If you set `var x=<?php echo $x; ?>` now you have a js variable to work with so x++; = 2. Ajax will communicate with your server (php) and will run the function with the variables you pass from js....look up wordpress and ajax, i dont have room here to expand.